# R, how could I get same results using function "for" to get the result from "replicate"?

Tags: r, for-loop, replicate

I would like to have a same result of this code using `replicate` function,

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
sides <- 6
p <- 1/sides
zs <- replicate(10000,{
x <- sample(1:sides,n,replace=TRUE)
(mean(x==6) - p) / sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)
})
```

by using `for` function. Code I've tried is like this.

```
n<-10000
side<-6
p<-1/side
set.seed(1)
for(i in 1:n){
z<-vector("numeric", n)
x<-sample(1:side, 100, replace=TRUE)
z[i]<-mean(x==6)
}
```

But code above doesn't work well.

Comment: I'm struggling to see why you would want to use `for` when a vectorized (and therefore usually better) way works perfectly fine...?

Comment: Take `z<-vector("numeric", n)` out of the loop. In the current case, at every iteration, z is initialized (again)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

set.seed(1)
n <- 100
sides <- 6
p <- 1/sides
zs <- replicate(10000,{
  x <- sample(1:sides,n,replace=TRUE)
  (mean(x==6) - p) / sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)
})

n<-10000
sides<-6
p<-1/sides
set.seed(1)
z<-vector("numeric", n)
for(i in 1:n){
  x<-sample(1:sides, 100, replace=TRUE)
  z[i]<-(mean(x==6) - p) / sqrt(p*(1-p)/100)
}

all(zs == z)
# TRUE
```

Comment: Checked this too late. Thanks a lot!!